# uploading photos to Craigslist with Python and Selenium

Tags: selenium, python-3.5, craigslist

using python3, selenium with firefox on windows10:
this program is simple. it jumps directly to craigslists 'post a new listing' page, uploads multiple photos, then submit. the problem im having is that i cannot control a dialog box to navigate to the correct file with selenium.

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://post.craigslist.org/k/lPbhT6Lh5RGBKb-uS1zr0g/g2NjN?lang=en&cc=us&s=editimage')
#opens to craigslists 'Upload/Edit Images' page

add_imgs_btn = browser.find_element_by_id('plupload')
#find the 'add images' button

add_imgs_btn.click()
#clicks the button which opens the dialog box, which is not operable from selenium
add_imgs_btn.send_keys(filepath)
```

Ive been doing some reading and i get the gist that i need to use send_keys() to the 'input file', but im still so new with selenium and programming in general, that i dont totally understand the concept. my idea was to use SendKeys from AutoIt, but i cant even figure out why AutoIt wont install to my computer. so im hoping someone can shed a little light on how to send the pre-decided pathname so i can upload photos. any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: how are you going through the initial radio button steps, where it asks for sale by owner/ what you're selling/ which category?

Answer (score 5):

You should not operate with `<button>` element, but with `<input>` instead, so use following code:

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_‌​keys(filepath)
```

Comment: where does 'html5_1ad1qt6re13snm058nqev3tb3' come from? i tried this, and got an error:' Unable to locate element:         {"method":"id","selector":"html5_1ad1qt6re13snm058nqev3tb3"}'

Comment: Oh... I guess this `Id` is dynamically changeable. Try `browser.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']").send_keys(filepath)`