# upload files with selenium webdriver python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'd like to use webdriver to pick a file but following other answers they do not work. They say just give the button a filepath, and this doesn't do anything. The upload looks like this after clicking the button:

[image]

This is what others say to do but doesn't work:

```
element = driver.find_element_by_name("file")
element.send_keys("/home/pavel/Desktop/949IH3GNHAo.jpg")
```

How can I submit files once I'm in a webdriver instance? Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't work"? What happens? Could you post the complete code including the url you are navigating to? Thanks.

Comment: After selecting the images file using sendkeys you need to click on upload button not on browse button again

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem solved at [uploading photos to Craigslist with Python and Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35805049/uploading-photos-to-craigslist-with-python-and-selenium)

```
def add_photo(self, filepath_to_photo):
    photo_filepath_input_box = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type='file']")
    photo_filepath_input_box.send_keys(filepath_to_photo) # "/home/cchilders/photos/myhouse/upperrightbedroom/photo1.png"
```

Answer (score 3):

Give AutoIT a try.

It's very easy to use and does the job.

Click on the Upload button first with the webdriver script, and then run the AutoIT .exe file with:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen('[name_of_your_script].exe')
```

Then give it a `wait.until`, using expected conditions, so it waits until the file finishes uploading.

An example AutoIT code below will select a file called "AAUPLOADFILE.png":

```
Local $hWnd=WinWait("[CLASS:#32770]","",10)

ControlFocus($hWnd,"","Edit1")

; Wait for 2 seconds.

  Sleep(2000)

  ControlSetText($hWnd, "", "Edit1", "AAUPLOADFILE.png")

  Sleep(2000)

; Click on the Open button

  ControlClick($hWnd, "","Button1");
```

Once you've got a script written, right-click the file and select Compile Script, which will create an .exe file.

Comment: this seems reasonable ali. do you have any example you can give about how to pass in the filename? If my python script can pass `FILENAME="AAUPLOADFILE.png"` and others, I would be thrilled. can I PM you?

Comment: the other issue is I don't use windows

Comment: I have never used ubuntu/linux for automation, sorry, and AutoIT is indeed a Windows only app. I have found this, though, they say it's an AutoIT equivalent for Linux: http://www.semicomplete.com/projects/xdotool/

Answer (score 2):

I'm also had problem with upload using Python and Selenium. 
It was because upload web form was not visible, and situated under the "upload image". (hidden upload form)

So i've made workaround.

```
# Try to open page with upload form
driver.get('https://bla.com/library/browser')

# Waiting for upload element with name upload-search-block
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "upload-search-block"))) 

# Relocate hidden upload form using JS 
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('upload-search-block').style.left='200px';")
driver.execute_script("document.getElementById('upload-search-block').style.top='170px';")

# And upload file in the end 
upload = driver.find_element_by_id('upload-search-block')
upload.send_keys('/tmp/custom_doc.docx')
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Upload windows are system windows and not in the webview. Selenium webdrivers can only control things inside a webview. You will need to hand off the task of choosing the file to another library like AutoIT.

Comment: I haven't been able to get that style to work. I'll try again I guess